# ExpandableListView; adding itms messes up expanded items

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I currently have an ExpandableListView that is handled by a custom BaseExpandableListAdapter object (see snippets below). The list is populated by Plate-objects that have a title shown at the group level, the expanded item then shown some information about the Plate, such as the make.

The trouble I'm having is that I need to dynamically add items to the list from the top, that is, inserting the new item att position 0 in the ArrayList of items. The problem I'm stuck with now is that if the item at position 1 is expanded, and I then add a new item, the "expanded status" is still on position 1, even though that item is now at position 2. Similarly the item previously at position 0 now gets expanded. The item now at position 2 is closed.

How do I keep control of open items when I add new items to the array? Should I not add new items directly into the array? Or do I need to override the notifyDataSetChanged() or something?

Snippet from the code that adds items (a button listener):

```
int _position = this.recent_list.indexOf( new_plate );
if ( _position == -1 ) {
    this.recent_list.add( 0, new_plate );
} else {
    this.recent_list.get( _position ).duplicate( ); //Just adds info that it exists twice
}
this.recent_list_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged( );
```

This is the custom adapter:

```
public class RecentExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Plate> list_data; 

    public RecentExpandableListAdapter( Context context, List<Plate> list_data ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list_data = list_data;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup( int plate_position ) {
        return this.list_data.get( plate_position );
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId( int plate_position ) {
        return plate_position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount( ) {
        return this.list_data.size( );
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild( int plate_position, int child_posititon ) {
        return this.list_data.get( plate_position );
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId( int plate_position, int child_position ) {
        return child_position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount( int plate_position ) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView( int plate_position, boolean is_expanded, View convert_view, ViewGroup parent ) {

        //The supplied view may be null, so we check if we need a new one
        if ( convert_view == null ) {
            LayoutInflater _inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) this.context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            convert_view = _inflater.inflate( R.layout.list_recent_group, parent, false );
        }

        TextView list_header = ( TextView ) convert_view.findViewById( R.id.label_recent_group_name );
        String header_title = getGroup( plate_position ).toString( );
        list_header.setTypeface( null, Typeface.BOLD );
        list_header.setText( header_title );
        return convert_view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView( int plate_position, final int child_position, boolean is_last_child, View convert_view, ViewGroup parent ) {

        //The supplied view may be null, so we check if we need a new one
        if ( convert_view == null ) {
            LayoutInflater infal_inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) this.context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            convert_view = infal_inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_recent_plate_info, parent, false );
        }

        TextView _make = ( TextView ) convert_view.findViewById( R.id.label_recent_plate_make_value );
        String child_text = getChild( plate_position, child_position ).toString( );
        _make.setText( child_text );
        return convert_view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds( ) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable( int plate_position, int child_position ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it myself just now!

```
@Override
public long getGroupId( int plate_position ) {
    return plate_position;
}
```

This method just returned the position, but when changed to a reference to the actual item, it now handles the expanded-status normally. I changed the method to:

```
 @Override
public long getGroupId( int plate_position ) {
    return this.list_data.get( plate_position ).hashCode( );
}
```